# HAVING clause affecting results

Tags: mysql, database, left-join, having

I have a query which shows sold and unsold products.

below is the query which is working correctly.

```
 SELECT p.product_id, 
    p.product_brand_id, 
    p.product_model_id, 
    p.product_subcategory_id,
    p.product_retail_price, 
    p.product_wholesale_price, 
    SUM(IFNULL(ps.product_quantity,0)) AS product_quantity_sold,
    SUM(IFNULL(ps.product_total_price,0)) AS total_price_sold, 
    pb.brand_name, 
    pm.model_name, 
    psub.subcategory_name
 FROM product p
 LEFT JOIN product_sold ps ON p.product_id = ps.product_id
 LEFT JOIN sales s ON ps.product_sales_id = s.sales_id
 JOIN product_brand pb ON pb.brand_id = p.product_brand_id
 JOIN product_model pm ON pm.model_id = p.product_model_id
 JOIN product_subcategory psub ON psub.subcategory_id = p.product_subcategory_id
 WHERE p.product_brand_id = $brand_id AND p.product_model_id = $model_id
   AND ( s.sales_id IS NULL
   OR ( s.sales_approved = '1' 
      AND s.sales_approved_time > '$start_timestamp'  
      AND s.sales_approved_time < '$end_timestamp'
      )
   )
   AND pb.brand_name NOT LIKE 'X%'
 GROUP BY p.product_id 
 ORDER BY product_quantity_sold DESC, pb.brand_name ASC, pm.model_name ASC
```

but onced added having to filter the list to only show

product that have stock or products that have been sold only, with this query below:

```
 SELECT p.product_id, 
    p.product_brand_id, 
    p.product_model_id, 
    p.product_subcategory_id,
    p.product_retail_price, 
    p.product_wholesale_price, 
    SUM(IFNULL(ps.product_quantity,0)) AS product_quantity_sold,
    SUM(IFNULL(ps.product_total_price,0)) AS total_price_sold, 
    SUM(IFNULL(pq.product_quantity,0)) AS total_stock, 
    pb.brand_name, 
    pm.model_name, 
    psub.subcategory_name
 FROM product p
 LEFT JOIN product_sold ps ON p.product_id = ps.product_id
 LEFT JOIN sales s ON ps.product_sales_id = s.sales_id
 LEFT JOIN product_stock pq ON p.product_id = pq.product_id
 JOIN product_brand pb ON pb.brand_id = p.product_brand_id
 JOIN product_model pm ON pm.model_id = p.product_model_id
 JOIN product_subcategory psub ON psub.subcategory_id = p.product_subcategory_id
 WHERE p.product_brand_id = $brand_id AND p.product_model_id = $model_id
   AND ( s.sales_id IS NULL
   OR ( s.sales_approved = '1' 
      AND s.sales_approved_time > '$start_timestamp'  
      AND s.sales_approved_time < '$end_timestamp'
      )
   )
   AND pb.brand_name NOT LIKE 'X%'
 GROUP BY p.product_id 
 HAVING total_stock > 0 OR product_quantity_sold > 0
 ORDER BY product_quantity_sold DESC, pb.brand_name ASC, pm.model_name ASC
```

Its kinda weird because im getting different results on each product for the variable below

```
product_quantity_sold
```

everything else in the result stays the same.

Comment: You are aware, I trust, that you're using a pernicious nonstandard MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`. If you're not aware of that, please read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-extensions.html When you use that extension, some items in your result set are unpredictable.

Comment: Yeah im aware of that, Ive used two different query to fetch sold results which always return the same so the GROUP BY its working correctly,  the problem is when I added left join into my product stock and then filter by HAVING its not giving me same results.

Comment: @OllieJones the question now will be how can I applied GROUP BY and Having together without afecting the results? since your example doesnt use any JOIN its not giving me a real help.

Comment: @bmacuer . . . It doesn't make sense.  The fields in the `having` are aggregated correctly, so they should be consistent.  Can you provide some sample data, the correct results, and the results as they appear in the second query?

Comment: @GordonLinoff http://186.107.241.14/phpmyadmin  root:rnarna1  

$brand_id = 1

$model_id = 5

s.sales_approved_time > '1356998400'  
s.sales_approved_time < '1388102400'

Comment: @GordonLinoff use both querys replace variables with the given numbers and you will see the difference of product_sold_quantity

Comment: I'm not sure that publishing your databases's *root* login credentials in a public forum is an entirely brilliant idea.

Comment: @eggyal is a testing server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `HAVING`.

Your second query joins with the `product_stock` table, whereas the first query does not.  Thus, every pre-aggregation record is repeated for each related stock entry.

`product_id = 577`, for example, appears in `product_stock` 8 times, so its value for `product_quantity_sold` is 8 times greater in the second query (184) than in the first (23).

Comment: youre right ill see how can I group this id or simply do separate querys and compare then in php and show desire results.

Answer (score 0):

Your group by clause is defective - you need to list all the non-aggregate columns:

```
...
group by p.product_id, 
    p.product_brand_id, 
    p.product_model_id, 
    p.product_subcategory_id,
    p.product_retail_price, 
    p.product_wholesale_price, 
    pb.brand_name, 
    pm.model_name, 
    psub.subcategory_name
```

in other database I know, not doing this would cause an error, but in mysql it's allowed but has special non-sql standard meaning of returning a single random row for each unique combination of values listed in the group by clause from the matching rows, *not* an aggregation.

Comment: yes you are right, but even if I group them I still getting product_quantity_sold times the amount of times product_id is JOIN in product_stock

Comment: `product_id`, `brand_id`, `model_id` and `subcategory_id` are PK in the `product`, `product_model`, `product_brand` and `product_subcategory` tables respectively - so grouping on `p.product_id` alone *guarantees* that values for the selected non-aggregated columns will be identical for each record in each group, thus relying on MySQL's non-standard extension to `GROUP BY` leads to determinate results (and saves on needlessly sorting by all such columns, which was the motivation for MySQL's extension in the first place).